# How to retrieve the two address as described below for vector pointer holding address of n vector each

Tags: c++

given a vector pointer of q size each holding addresses of n vector. Now given two indexes(k,l say) how to use the k to get the address of vector and later using l to get the element

Comment: `*q[k]` is the vector (or `q->at(k)`), `(*q[k])[i]` would be the element (or `q.at(k)->at(i)`). If `q` is a vector-of-pointers-to-vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much will depend on just exactly what you are describing. My best understanding is that you have a `std::vector` of *pointers-to-vectors* to some type (using `<int>` for the example below. If that is the case, that would mean you have something similar to:

```
    std::vector  <int>  iv1 = { 1, 2, 3 },  /* 3 vectors int */
                        iv2 = { 2, 3, 4 },
                        iv3 = { 3, 4, 5 };
    /* vector holding address of each vector int */
    std::vector <std::vector <int>*> piv = { &iv1, &iv2, &iv3 };
```

So you have a vector holding the addresses of other vectors to `<int>` (or whatever your actual type is).

To access individual elements with auto-ranged `for` loops to access each of the members. You first loop will be a loop that produces *pointers-to-vectors* as the type to iterate, so the nested loop will need to dereference the value to access the vectors themselves, e.g.

```
    for (auto& pv : piv) {          /* loop over vector of pointers */
        for (auto& e : *pv)         /* loop over each vector <int> */
            std::cout << " " << e;  /* output each element */
        std::cout << '\n';          /* tidy up with newline */
    }
```

**Output**

```
 1 2 3
 2 3 4
 3 4 5
```

You can access individual elements using 2-indexes using either `(*piv[k])[i]` notation, or using `piv.at(i)->at(j)` notation, e.g.

```
    /* output indexes 1, 1 using index notation */
    std::cout << "\n(*piv[1])[1]: " << (*piv[1])[1] << "\n\n";
    /* output indexes 1, 1 using at() member function */
    std::cout << "piv.at(1)->at(1): " << piv.at(1)->at(1) << '\n';
```

(**note:** the reason the `(...)` is required around, e.g. `(*piv[1])` in [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence))

**Output**

```
(*piv[1])[1]: 3

piv.at(1)->at(1): 3
```

Putting it altogether in a short example, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {

    std::vector  <int>  iv1 = { 1, 2, 3 },  /* 3 vectors int */
                        iv2 = { 2, 3, 4 },
                        iv3 = { 3, 4, 5 };
    /* vector holding address of each vector int */
    std::vector <std::vector <int>*> piv = { &iv1, &iv2, &iv3 };

    std::cout << "for (auto& pv : piv)\n    for (auto& e : *pv)\n\n";

    for (auto& pv : piv) {          /* loop over vector of pointers */
        for (auto& e : *pv)         /* loop over each vector <int> */
            std::cout << " " << e;  /* output each element */
        std::cout << '\n';          /* tidy up with newline */
    }

    /* output indexes 1, 1 using index notation */
    std::cout << "\n(*piv[1])[1]: " << (*piv[1])[1] << "\n\n";
    /* output indexes 1, 1 using at() member function */
    std::cout << "piv.at(1)->at(1): " << piv.at(1)->at(1) << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/vect_ptr_to_vect
for (auto& pv : piv)
    for (auto& e : *pv)

 1 2 3
 2 3 4
 3 4 5

(*piv[1])[1]: 3

piv.at(1)->at(1): 3
```

Look things over and let me know if I understood your question correctly, and whether you have any further questions about the content.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow your question in details, and if i got you right, you are interested in something like the following:

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int main()
{

    vector<vector<int>*> vec_q;

    vector<vector<int>*>* pvec_q = &vec_q;

    vector<int> int_vector;
    vector<int>* pint_vector = &int_vector;


    (*pvec_q)[0] = pint_vector;

    (*(*pvec_q)[0])[0] = 1;
}
```